# IIS 404 Error when I try to access an action using attribute based routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this area setting from my route config so when the page gets loaded, the default action will be directed to

`http://localhost:50333/practice/home/index`

I set them up by using this code:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
 ).DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary(new { area = "Practice" });
```

From one of my actions, I have an action that is decorated with attribute based routing which is:

```
 [Route("r/{topic}/{poster}")]
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Access(string topic, string poster)
 {
     return View();
 }
```

But i get `HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found` If I try to access it with 
`http://localhost:50333/practice/home/r/asd/asd/`

Comment: Do you have `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` in your route config and a `RoutePrefix` on the controller?

Comment: Yeah turned out that I am missing that one. What do you mean by `RoutePrefix`?

Comment: The prefix was for `practice/home`

Comment: Oh I dont think so, how do I do that?

Comment: Add `RoutePrefix` attribute to the controller class.